# TypeScript: Accessing `this` of "parent" function (Java-like MyClass.this)

Tags: typescript, closures, this

In JavaScript, due to it's lack of nice native syntax for array iteration, it's quite common to use `[].forEach((item)=>{...})`;
However, that closure changes the value of `this`.

In Java, for such cases, there's the syntax `MyClass.this`, which allows to refer to the "upper" `this`.

Is there something such in TypeScript? Or in plan? I can imagine that being transpiled to store the `this` reference and use it in the closure.

The code:

```
public fromJSON(input: Object, clazz?: typeof FrameModel): T
{
    const service_this = this;
    if (clazz === void 0){
        var disc = input[GraphJSONtoTsModelsService.DISCRIMINATOR];
        if (disc instanceof Array)
            disc = disc[0];
        if (disc === void 0)
            throw new Error(`Given object doesn't specify "${GraphJSONtoTsModelsService.DISCRIMINATOR}" and no target class given: ` + JSON.stringify(input));
        clazz = this.getTypeScriptClassByDiscriminator(disc);
    }

    if (clazz == null){
        throw new Error(`No class found for discriminator ${disc}: ` + JSON.stringify(input));
    }

    let result = new FrameModel(input["_id"]);
    //result.setVertexId(input["_id"]);
    //console.log("We have a frame now: " + result);

    //for (let name in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(input) ){
    let propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(input);
    for (let i = 0; i < propNames.length; i++) {
        let name = propNames[i];
        let val = input[name];
        // Properties
        if (typeof val === 'string' || typeof val === 'number'){
            let beanPropName = clazz.graphPropertyMapping[name] || name; // Use same if not defined.
            result[beanPropName] = val;
        }
        // Adjacent - input prop name is graph edge name.
        if (typeof val === 'object'){
            let beanPropName = clazz.graphRelationMapping[name] || name; // Use same if not defined.
            let info = RelationInfo.parse(beanPropName);

            //console.log(`propName: ${name}  beanPropName: ${beanPropName}  isArray: ${isArray}`);
            let direction = val["direction"];
            let items = [];
            if (val["vertices"] instanceof Array) {
                val["vertices"].forEach((vertex) => {
                    let item: Object;
                    let mode = vertex[GraphJSONtoTsModelsService.MODE] || "vertex";
                    if (mode == "vertex")
                        item = service_this.fromJSON(vertex);
                    else if (mode == "link")
                    {
                        let link: string = vertex["link"];
                        item = service_this.fromLink(link);
                    }
                    //console.log(`item: ${item}  vertex: ${JSON.stringify(vertex)}`);
                    items.push(item);
                });
            }
            result[info.beanPropName] = info.isArray ? items : (items[0]);
        }
    }

    return <T> result;
}
```

Comment: No, in fact the arrow functions save the context of `this`. And no, there's no js/ts equivalent for the java `Class.this`.

Comment: Save to where? `this` in a lambda points to a different object, with constructor `Function`, which I assume is the lambda itself.

Comment: Added the code. I will also gladly accept any tips not related to the question ;-)

Comment: Your code seem ok, How are you using this `fromJSON` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include your real code, so I don't know how you run this `[].forEach((item)=>{...});` you mentioned, but arrow functions do keep the context for `this`.

In [MDN it says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function
>   expressions and lexically binds the this value...

And:

> An arrow function does not create it's own this context, rather it
>   captures the this value of the enclosing context, so the following
>   code works as expected.

In the [typescript docs it says](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-and-arrow-functions):

```
Arrow functions capture the this where the function is created rather than where it is invoked
```

And here's an example:

```
class A {
    private factor: number;

    constructor(factor: number) {
        this.factor = factor;
    }

    public multiply(items: number[]): number[] {
        return items.map(item => item * this.factor);
    }
}

let a = new A(2);
a.multiply([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%09private%20factor%3A%20number%3B%0A%09%0A%09constructor(factor%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%09%09this.factor%20%3D%20factor%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09public%20multiply(items%3A%20number%5B%5D)%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20items.map(item%20%3D%3E%20item%20*%20this.factor)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A(2)%3B%0Aa.multiply(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B2%2C%204%2C%206%2C%208%2C%2010%5D))

If this doesn't work for you then please update your question with the actual code you're having problems with.

Comment: I see, maybe I am using wrong syntax?  `(...) => {...}`

Comment: The other syntax produces the same JS. I'll check again in my code.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I guess I had some glitch in my code. Thanks!